# Fatal error wp-blog-header.php on line 16

Tags: wordpress

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp() in /home/httpd/vhosts/mysite.ch/public_html/website.ch/wp-blog-header.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/httpd/vhosts//mysite.ch/public_html/website.ch/index.php(17): require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/httpd/vhosts//mysite.ch/public_html/website.ch/wp-blog-header.php on line 16

Hello , i have some websites and i get this messeges in every approximately  3 months. i get this error message from my websites when i want to login enter or sometimes spontaneously.
I researched abut it but i couldnt find how to fix problem. Everytime i restore my website.Can you help me please I would be very grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: It's better to add code where error is pointing to. also yours question's title can not say the problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

1- Access your website files using FTP

2- Check if any of the files has size 0, especially `wp-load.php`,

3- If so, download the specific version of WordPress from official page and replace all the 0 sized files with files from original WP zip.

Answer (score -1):

That's malware.
1.You should scan your server,
2.Delete all infected files,
3.Restore wp-blog-header.php with a default one. You can download a fresh version via this link: wordpress.org/download/releases/

You won't be able to restore the account until all infected files are deleted